# Positivity of this improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

I am not relieved of the following problem and trip.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a small parameter, $a>0$ be a given constant, $x_{\varepsilon}\in(0,a)$ be a given sequence such that $x_{\varepsilon}\to a$ as $\varepsilon\to0$ and $f:[0,a)\times[0,a)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
$$
f(x,x)=+\infty\ \text{for all $x\in[0,a)$},\quad f(x,y)>0\ \text{for all $(x,y)\in[0,a)\times[0,x)$}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{y\to a}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon},y)=+\infty,\quad \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon},y)>0\quad\text{for all $y\in[0,a)$}
$$
and $y\mapsto \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon},y)$ is continuous function on $[0,a)$.

> Answer if or not the followings hold:
>   $$
> (1) \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{0}^{x_{\varepsilon}-\varepsilon}f(x_{\varepsilon},y)dy\ge0
> $$
>   $$
> (2) \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{0}^{x_{\varepsilon}-\varepsilon}f(x_{\varepsilon},y)dy=\int_{0}^{a}f(a,y)dy
> $$

Of course, if (2) is true, (1) automatically holds.
However, I think that (2) does not be expected although I don't know whether it holds.
The typical example of $f$ is
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{g(x,y)}{(x-y)^{3/2}},
$$
where $g$ has ***good*** properties, for example, it is continuous on compact sets.

I'm glad if you give solution or counterexample if exists.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $[0,a)\times[0,a)$, but then you have $f(x,x)$ for $x\in[0,a]$ and $f(a,y)$. Did you mean to write $[0,a]\times[0,a)$?

Comment: @Math1000 I'm sorry. These is in the sense of limitation. I now modify my question.